# Is beachcombing on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is beachcombing an outdoor activity? Are beachcombing questions on-topic?

For example, a photo of something odd found on a beach somewhere in the world, with the question: *what is this?*. Or recommendations for spectacular beachcombing. Does this fit on outdoors? Or better or travel?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I think beachcombing is on-topic. It is an inherently outdoors activity, and in many ways similar to geocaching, which is clearly on-topic.

Comment: ...I agree it should be on topic, but similar to geocaching???

Comment: I think it's fairly similar (though I don't do either, so maybe less so than I think). They're both essentially walking around looking for things, though the GPS on geocaching makes it somewhat more guided.

Comment: hahahahaha - walking around looking for things. I like that :-)